# Float’: can’t convert nil into Float (TypeError)

Tags: ruby, csv

am trying to read data from a csv file,but i keep getting this error "Float’: can’t convert nil into Float (TypeError)",below is my code and the text in the csv file.

csv file

```
"Date","ISBN","Price"

"2013-04-12","978-1-9343561-0-4",39.45

"2013-04-13","978-1-9343561-6-6",45.67

"2013-04-14","978-1-9343560-7-4",36.95
```

CsvReader class

```
    require 'csv'

  require_relative 'book_in_stock'

   class CsvReader
    def initialize
        @books_in_stock = []
    end

    def read_in_csv_data(csv_file)
        CSV.foreach(csv_file, headers: true) do |row|
            @books_in_stock << BookInStock.new(row["ISBN"], row["PRICE"])
        end
    end

    def total_value_in_stock
        sum = 0.0
        @books_in_stock.each{|book| sum += book.price}
        sum
    end
end
```

BookInStock class

```
class BookInStock 
    attr_reader :isbn, :price
    #@amount = gets.chomp.to_i
    def initialize(isbn,price)
        @isbn = isbn
        @price = Float(price)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the function read_in_csv_data you used upper case for addressing the
row 'PRICE'. But in the CSV you had camel case 'Price' as the header.

So changing the BookInStock.new call parameter to row["Price"] solves the problem.

```
def read_in_csv_data(csv_file)
    CSV.foreach(csv_file, headers: true) do |row|
        @books_in_stock << BookInStock.new(row["ISBN"], row["Price"])
    end
end
```